# Trying to create a replay feature for a Turn-based game (very newbie)

Tags: python

I'm currently playing a trading card game called Hearthstone which is made by blizzard. The game is pretty good, but lacks basic features that any game that calls itself "competitive" should have, like stat tracking and replay.
So as I said in the title, I'm trying to create a (very crude and poorly done) script that let's me record every match I play. Due to my lack of programming skills, 80% of the script is just a bunch of code that I borrowed from all sorts of places and adapted to make it do what I wanted.
**The idea is to make it work like this**:

1. I take a picture of every turn I play. It might become annoying, but I do not dare to think about implementing OCR as to make the script take a picture at the start of every turn by itself. Would be awesome but I just can't do it...

   The game sends every picture to the desktop (no need to code that).
2. At the end of the game I run the script

2.1 Every match is going to have a numbered folder so the script creates that. The folders are going to be called "Match1", "Match2", etc. *You can see how poorly written that is because I made it on my own :P*

```
import sys
import os
import shutil

def checkFolder():
os.path.join('D:\Hearthstone\Replays\Match1')
matchNumber=1
while os.path.exists("D:\\Hearthstone\\Replays\\Match"+ str(matchNumber)) is True:
    matchNumber=matchNumber + 1
else:
    os.makedirs("D:\Hearthstone\Replays\Match"+str(matchNumber))
```

**2.2** Script sends the photos from Desktop to the recently created folder. The Problem is that I do not know how to make the script change the destination folder to the newest folder created. *I did not write this part of the code, i merely adapted it. Source: http://tinyurl.com/srcbh*

```
folder = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Felipe\\', 'Desktop') # Folder in which the images are in. 
destination = os.path.join('D:\\Hearthstone\\Replays\\', 'match9999') #**Destination needs to be the newest folder and I dont know how to implement that...
extmove = 'png' # The extension you wish to organize. 
num = 0 # Variable simply to use after to count images. 

for filename in os.listdir(folder): #Run through folder.
        extension = filename.split(".")[-1] # This strips the extensions ready to check and places into the extension
        if extension == extmove: # If statement. If the extension of the file matches the one set previously then..
            shutil.move(folder + "\\" + filename, destination) # Move the file from the folder to the destination folder. Also previously set. 
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        
print (filename, extension)
```

And that's it! **I need help with step 2.2.** I'd certainly appreciate the help!
Now, the reason I made such a big post is because I wanted to expose my idea and hopefully inspire someone to take on a similar project seriously. Hearthstone has thousands of players  that could benefit from it, not to mention that this seems to be a fairly easy task to someone with more experience.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally got it to work!

```
import sys
import os
import shutil

def sendPhotos():
    matchNumber=1
    photos_dest = "D:\\Hearthstone\\Replays\\Match"
    while os.path.exists(photos_dest+ str(matchNumber)): #creates the name of the folder "Match1", "Match2", etc.
        matchNumber=matchNumber + 1
    else:
        photos_destination = photos_dest+str(matchNumber)
        os.makedirs(photos_destination)
        for files in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Felipe\\Desktop'):#only png files are moved
            if files.endswith(".png"):
                shutil.move(files, photos_destination)

sendPhotos()
```

Thank you to those who gave me some answers! I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

This sees which matches are in the folder and takes the lowest number for the folder.

```
folder = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Felipe\\', 'Desktop') # Folder in which the images are in. 
recorded_matches_location = 'D:\\Hearthstone\\Replays\\'
match_number = 1
match_name = 'match1'
while match_name in os.listdir(recorded_matches_location):
    match_number = 1 + match_number
    match_name = 'match' + str(match_number) # corrected it! there must be a string and not a variable
destination = os.path.join(recorded_matches_location, match_name) #**Destination needs to be the newest folder and I dont know how to implement that...
extmove = 'png' # The extension you wish to organize. 
num = 0 # Variable simply to use after to count images. 

for filename in os.listdir(folder): #Run through folder.
        extension = filename.split(".")[-1] # This strips the extensions ready to check and places into the extension
        if extension == extmove: # If statement. If the extension of the file matches the one set previously then..
            shutil.move(folder + "\\" + filename, destination) # Move the file from the folder to the destination folder. Also previously set. 
        num = num + 1
        print(num)

print (filename, extension)
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer! So I tried to use your code and it works, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. It is not sending the files to newest folder, it's just sending the photos to the first folder called "Match1" even though I have new ones (Match2, Match3...). Do you know how to fix that? PS: on line 7 is it match or 'match'?

Comment: 'match' then it may work.. maybe you can figure out the rest based on my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I actually spent some time trying to fix it. The problem is that I was unfamiliar with the code there especially because I hadn't written most of it. After I understood what each statement did, things became more clear. Anyways, I started it from scratch and was able to finally get it to work. Sorry if came off as lazy when I sent you that comment, but I'm just new to all that stuff so once I got stuck, the whole task became discouraging/boring.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, the fact that you identified a problem and put together a solution shows that you certainly don't lack programming skills.  Give yourself some credit.  You just need more practice. :)

This should be better, I haven't run it, so there might be some errors :P

```
def checkFunction(base_dir='D:\\Hearthstone\\Replays\\'):  #set this as a parameter with a default
    match_number = 1
    if os.path.exists(base_dir):  #if the base directory doesn't exist you'll have a bad time
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(base_dir, 'Match{0}'.format(match_number)))
            match_number += 1
        new_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Match{0}'.format(match_number))
        os.makedirs(new_dir)
        return new_dir
```

For the function checkFolder, I suggest having it return the new directory name (as above).  You'll also need to indent all the lines below it so python knows those lines are part of that function (this might just be a formatting issue on SO though).

Then, once the checkFolder function is working properly, all you have the change in 2.2 is:

```
destination = checkFolder()
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer and your kind words! As you said, the problem with the indentation only happened after I posted it. So no worries, that part of the code was working! The code you sent me looks much better but it has a small problem. On line 4 it gives me a syntax error. At the moment I haven't found the reason but I'll have to admit that I didn't try too much to fix that because step 2.2 is the real problem atm and I'm already stuck on that :/.I'll definitely work on that after I make the whole script work, though! Also, if you could find a solution to step 2.2 I'd be ver